# Incorrect if statement

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a associative array, when i'm looping the array i try to make a statement which output an incorrect answer.

```
foreach($search as $a=>$b)
{ 
  foreach($b as $c) {

      if($b == 'folder')
      {
        print_r($b);
        $dir = true;
      }
  }
}
```

The following code outputs 0 and 'folder'. When `$b` equals 0 it is incorrect because `$b` is supposed to match 'folder'.

### print_r of `$search`

```
array (size=3)
  'status' => string 's_search' (length=8)
  'files' => 
    array (size=1)
      'file' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
  'folders' => 
    array (size=1)
      'folder' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '1081483096' (length=10)
          'name' => string 'asdf' (length=4)
          'match_type' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

Comment: What is the value of `$search`? Can you do a `print_r($search)`?

Comment: *"The following code returns 0 and 'folder'"*. The above code returns nothing. It's not clear at all what you're asking

Comment: There is no `return` in there and with a missing semi colon that should not even be working, does it even work?

Comment: That code just became nonsensical. Is `$b` a string or an array?! And if your problem is that `0` equals `'folder'`, look up value comparison rules. Yes, PHP may cast your values if you allow it to.

Comment: Sorry, i mean the return value of the print_r($b). Print_r($b) returns 0 and 'folder' because it loops two times.

Comment: $search is a associative array.

Comment: Guys, the OP is using "return" to mean "outputs" here. Get over it.

Comment: @user2615039 If you're going to ask a question around problem code, **copy and paste the problem code into your question**

Comment: `$b == 'folder'` incorrect hence $b is array

Comment: I am guessing you are comparing $c instead of $b?

Comment: Apparently I gave an answer that worked due to the change in comparison operators... and I still don't know what the objective or desired output was.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify what you are doing nor what you are expecting as output, I'm assuming that you are only interested in the `folders` of your `$search` array.

```
foreach($search['folders'] as $k => $v) {
    if($k === 'folder') {
        print_r($v);
        $dir = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will try to work on that! I change the double equal sign '==' to triple '===' sign it works great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here **$b** is an `array`. So, `before loop` you should check whether it is an **array** or **not** like,

```
foreach($search as $a=>$b)
{ 
    if(is_array($b) and !empty($b))
    {
       foreach($b as $c) {
          //your code
       }
    }
    elseif(is_string($b) and $b=='folder')
    {
        print_r($b);
        $dir = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you simply want this?

```
if (isset($search['folders']['folder'])) {
    var_dump($search['folders']['folder']);
    $dir = true;
}
```